# how to retrieve an array of data from firebase

Tags: python, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi there I have tried this in a couple of ways, but basically, I have an array of data in my firebase database that I uploaded using Python. In Python I added everything to an array and uploaded it to the database. In Swift I have tried to retrieve the data like this

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase


class CSGOView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var teams: [String] = []
    var times: [String] = []




    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTwo: UITableView!
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "Took the url out it is the right url to the database im sure")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getTeamsAndTimes()
    }

    func getTeamsAndTimes() {
        //let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("Teams").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String: String] ?? [:]

            for team in value {
                print(team.key)
                print(team.value)
            }

            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell? = nil
        return cell!

    }

}
```

This doesn't work though when the view loads nothing is printed to the console. I have the method run in the ViewDidLoad().

here is how the data looks like in the firebase database(I have to go So I will upload it when  I get back) roughly it is like

Teams
  0: "teamname"
  1: "teamtwo"

so there is teams then a plus sign and it drops down to show a dictionary with 0 as the key and "teamname" as the value. I don't have the random id before the keys and values if that helps. I used the set method instead of the push method in python. the set method uploads the data without the id.

turns out I can't upload images anyways till I have 10 rep.

https://ibb.co/dSp5ka

the link above takes you to how the firebase database looks like

Comment: Cant really help, if we can't see the database structure, Edit your question with the *viewDidLoad* function.

Comment: I updated the code to show the entire class I also added the database picture onto that website at the bottom. @Dravidian

Comment: you gotta make sure that your security rules permit the retrieval of the data

Comment: figured that could be the problem, would I have to do that by providing a user? or can I see an example of how to set that. In another class I have a simalar method that gets the username from the user. it goes something like. ref.child("User").child(userID). I think the userID is what is allowing me to access the data. but since the data that I am extracting now does not have a userID as one of the children in the database as seen by the picture.

Comment: I cannot edit my post some I'm putting your @ here @Dravidian

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript , You can directly give a reference to firebaseArray and get the value as array from firebase.

```
  var TeamRef = ref.child('Teams');
  var TeamInfo = $firebaseArray(TeamRef);
```

Not sure about Swift/Python.

Comment: I think you wrote that in javascript, not sure though I could be wrong. Do you know the swift equivalent, if that is swift then I apologize.

Comment: Sorry this is javascript.

Comment: Oh well thank you for the help I might use that If I make this app in cordova or something, but I need the swift equivalent which I think is a lot different.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

```
let value = snapshot.value as? [String: String] ?? [:]

for team of value {
   print(team.key)
   print(team.value)
}
```

Comment: This is better, but it still just prints nothing to the console, no errors. It doesn't even make whitespace in the console.

Comment: So, After further reasearch I have firgured out that the for loop does not even execute

Comment: If I print('hello') after or before the for block that code will execute, but anything inside the for loop does not execute at least I don't think @Luan Tran

Comment: Hi, can you check your "rules" in firebase? [Rules](https://ibb.co/feN3ov)

Answer (score 0):

By the information given by you in your above posts; This is the best i can tell -

***Security rules***

```
{
"rules": {

 ".write" : "auth != null",
 ".read" : "auth != null",

  "Teams" :{

     ".read" : "true",   // Make it publicly accessible 
    ".write" : "true",


  }
 }
}
```

***Code***

```
var dict = NSMutableDictionary()    // Global Declaration


FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("shows").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snapshot) in

       for each in Snapshot.children{

            self.dict.setObject((each as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as! String, forKey: String((each as! FIRDataSnapshot).key) as! NSCopying)
            print(self.dict)

        }

    })
```