# how to remove "snap" before the item in the array from firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, database, firebase

I have a function that returns an array from my firebase database. The problem is it always prints snap (number where item is located so ex. 0) first before returning the value in the database so for example it will print [snap (0) teamname]

How would I get rid of this snap (num) at the beginning of the the value. Maybe there is some kind of framework that removes certain phrases out of arrays? let me know thanks here is my code and the database.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase


class CSGOView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var teams: [String] = []
    var times: [String] = []




    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTwo: UITableView!
    let teamsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "can't have this info sorry, basically it goes straight to Teams in the database")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getTeamsAndTimes()
    }

    func getTeamsAndTimes() {
        teamsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let d = snapshot.children.allObjects
            print(d)
            for child in snapshot.children {
                print(child)
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell? = nil
        return cell!

    }

}
```

and here is the image that shows the database, and how its laid out.

https://ibb.co/dSp5ka

and here is the console output

```
[Snap (0) FaZe Clan, Snap (1) Natus Vincere, Snap (2) Natus Vincere, Snap (3) FaZe Clan, Snap (4) HellRaisers, Snap (5) G2 Esports, Snap (6) G2 Esports, Snap (7) HellRaisers, Snap (8) NRG Esports, Snap (9) Counter Logic Gaming, Snap (10) Counter Logic Gaming, Snap (11) NRG Esports, Snap (12) OpTic Gaming, Snap (13) Rush, Snap (14) Rush, Snap (15) OpTic Gaming]
Snap (0) FaZe Clan
Snap (1) Natus Vincere
Snap (2) Natus Vincere
Snap (3) FaZe Clan
Snap (4) HellRaisers
Snap (5) G2 Esports
Snap (6) G2 Esports
Snap (7) HellRaisers
Snap (8) NRG Esports
Snap (9) Counter Logic Gaming
Snap (10) Counter Logic Gaming
Snap (11) NRG Esports
Snap (12) OpTic Gaming
Snap (13) Rush
Snap (14) Rush
Snap (15) OpTic Gaming
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access `snapshot.value` to get your team name.

```
func getTeamsAndTimes() {
    teamsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.teams = []
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let team = (child as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as? String {
                 self.teams.append(team)
            }               
        }
        //Reload the tabelView after that
        self.tableViewTwo.reloadData()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Now in `numberOfRowsInSection` return the `teams` array `count` instead of `3`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.teams.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifer", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = teams[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS. You are the best dude, been working on this all night. Thanks you for even showing me how to update the cell and all that I really appreciate it. If I may ask how did you get so good at programming in swift? do you just work for a swift app making company did you read and make a lot of apps? Any recomendations for me? thanks for the answer it works perfectly @Nirav D

Comment: @DevinTripp Welcome mate :) Mate if you read apple swift documentation then you will get enough knowledge to develop Application in swift lang, no big task :)

Comment: You're telling me you read all the documentation from apple and that is the only resource that you used. I wish it was that easy. I don't understand a lot of the syntax, so it's a little hard for me. I accepted the answer I really appreciate it D!

Comment: @DevinTripp I'm not saying to read whole documentation, you can read this programming guide  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309 When ever you face issue with some specific type read about that type

Comment: @DevinTripp Also I have check this question of your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869431/how-to-retrieve-an-array-of-data-from-firebase if you say I will post answer there also so it will helps to other looking with the same issue.

Comment: Oh ok thanks I'll keep that in mind in the future. And yeah I'll check it as the answer. Hopefully it will help anyone looking to grab an array from a database. One thing that I noticed when I run the code is it doesn't do anything to the table view. It doesn't add anything to the view. I'll post another question with more details if I can't figure it out. Just wondering if you know of any common issues.

Comment: @DevinTripp Don't get you, Are you not able to see data in tableView? Also should I post answer in this question of your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869431/how-to-retrieve-an-array-of-data-from-firebase ?

Comment: So I made a question to what I am trying to ask here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894935/swift-items-not-showing-up-in-my-table-view-with-customized-cell                             I am not able to see any data in the TableView