# Swift - Items not showing up in my table view with customized cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

My array teams is not showing up in my tabe view. I am looking for common problems with this.

In the code below I gather data from my firebase and put that data into an array called teams. after I get the teams array I then put that array into two arrays because I have two labels in my custom cell called teamOneLabel and teamTwoLable.

So after I do all that I then return how many table cells there should be by dividing the teams array by 2. Then I add the data from the cells into each label. The problem is when ever the view loads it shows just a regular table view and it does not display any data.

I think it is possible that the data takes a little bit to be put into the teams array. For example if I print the teams array after the getTeamsAndTimes() function it will display nothing in the console, but If I print it after it adds the data in the function itself it works fine.

After further reasearch I have realized that I the custom cell is not displaying at all leading me to believe there is something wrong with my identifier or something. I'm not sure.

Here is the code for the view that shows the table view...

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase


class CSGOView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewView: UITableView!

    var teams: [String] = []
    var times: [String] = []
    var teamOneArray: [String] = []
    var teamTwoArray: [String] = []




    let teamsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "")
    let timesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "Not showing these")

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getTeamsAndTimes()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getTeamsAndTimes()
        self.tableViewView.reloadData()
    }

    func getTeamsAndTimes() {
        //let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        teamsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let team = (child as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as? String {
                    self.teams.append(team)
                }
            }
            self.findTeamOneAndTeamTwo(teams: self.teams)
            print(self.teamOneArray)
            print(self.teamTwoArray)
            //Reload the tabelView after that
            self.tableViewView.reloadData()
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        timesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let team = (child as! FIRDataSnapshot).value as? String {
                    self.times.append(team)
                }
            }

            //Reload the tabelView after that
            self.tableViewView.reloadData()
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func teamsWithTimes() -> [String : String] {
        var timesTeams: [String: String] = [:]



        return timesTeams
    }

    func findTeamOneAndTeamTwo(teams: [String]) {
        //Find the count then divide
        var i = 0

        //check if its even
        for team in teams{
            if i%2 == 0 {
                self.teamOneArray.append(team)
            } else {
                self.teamTwoArray.append(team)
            }

            i += 1
        }



    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.teams.count/2
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.TeamOneLabel?.text = teamOneArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.TeamTwoLabel?.text = teamTwoArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

}
```

here is the code for the custom cell...

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var TeamTwoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TeamTwoPhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TeamOnePhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TeamOneLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {


        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

here is what the table view looks like...

[image: The View]

What's really wierd is that I have a label in the custom cell called VS and thats not even showing up.

[image]

that is the storyboard with the cell and tableview

Comment: What is the identifier you have set in storyboards for your prototype cell? Is it "cell"? If you are setting up your cells via storyboard, it would be easier to check what is going on if you can upload a copy of your project somewhere and provide a link to it.

Comment: yes the identifier is called "cell"

Comment: I uploaded how the storyboard looks, I can upload a copy of the project if that would be better. @Fahim

Comment: Yes, if I have the project, then I can go through it to see what is going on quickly and get you an answer :) Otherwise, I'd have to replicate your project to see what might be going wrong and that's a bit more effort :)

Comment: @DevinTripp Why you are returning `self.teams.count/2` in `numberOfRowInSection` and also you are accessing `teamOneArray` and `teamTwoArray` in `cellForRow`.

Comment: @NiravD So in my custom cell I have two labels that I want to change to display the teams, well the teams array has all the teams but I want the first team to display on the first label and the next team to display on the next label, and from what I know the only way to do that was to make two different arrays. One would be all the teams that will display first and the second array would be all the teams that would display in the second label

Comment: @NiravD the reason I have the teams array divided by two is because one cell will have two teams. So if the array has 42 team names in it and two of them will display on each cell then I will only have 21 cells

Comment: @DevinTripp Check your `delegate` and `datasource` of `tableView`` is connected or not?

Comment: @NiravD yes it is

Comment: @NiravD Actually I guess it wasn't it said it was like two days ago

Comment: @NiravD ok now its working but giving me an index out of range error

Comment: Lol as NiravD has pointed out my datasource and delegate was not connected. I need to double check these things. Its all fixed now if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it @NiravD

Comment: @DevinTripp Check my solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the `delegate` and `datasource` of `tableView` after that instead of returning array of `count / 2` return count of array that have less object.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return teamOneArray < teamTwoArray ? teamOneArray.count : teamTwoArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.TeamOneLabel?.text = teamOneArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.TeamTwoLabel?.text = teamTwoArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

If you want to show the last object of array that have one more value than you need to add empty string to the array that have one less object.

```
func findTeamOneAndTeamTwo(teams: [String]) {
    //Find the count then divide
    var i = 0

    //check if its even
    for team in teams{
        if i%2 == 0 {
            self.teamOneArray.append(team)
        } else {
            self.teamTwoArray.append(team)
        }
        i += 1
    }
    if (self.teamOneArray.count != self.teamTwoArray.count) {
        if (self.teamOneArray.count < self.teamTwoArray.count) {
            self.teamOneArray.append("")
        }
        else {
            self.teamTwoArray.append("")
        }
    }
}
```

Now in `numberOfRowsInSection` return count for one of the array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return teamOneArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.TeamOneLabel?.text = teamOneArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.TeamTwoLabel?.text = teamTwoArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```